# Save site as template do not include list attachments

Tags: 2010, site-template

I'm trying to create a site template which include several lists. On these lists, we've got items with attachments. I'm quite surprised not to see attachment in the WSP generated... I've created a document library and this time attachments were included in the WSP.

Basically, I can switch my list to a library, but do you know if this is intended or if it is unexpected.

Comment: Are you selecting the checkbox 'Include Content'? Is the list item data being included, but not the individual attachments?

Comment: Yes, list items are included, except individual attachment(s).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately exporting site templates works far from perfectly...

It is more than likely that this is per design, as i have discovered several other caveats with this functionality. The most annoying being that export does not work with Publishing sites (i know you can hack around this, but the fact stays that it is **not supported** and probably for good reasons).

You can try exporting the list as stp file including content instead.

i only use export site to import into a temporary Visual Studio solution, so I can copy the declarative XML into my "real" VS project